# How to deselect a radio button if another one with a different name is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive got a group of radio buttons for different meals and i want to have them to have different names for each group.

Here is an image of what i have.

[image]

They can only select either, a Main Meal, a Jacket Potato or a Salad.

If they try to select a main, Then change their mind and select a salad it needs to deselect the main meal.

The radio buttons are labeled like the following,

Group 1:lunch_main
Group 2:lunch_jacketpotato
Group 3:lunch_salad

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why do you need different names for each group? Just use the same name for Main Meal, Jacket Potato and Salad and differentiate them with `value`.

Comment: Because im using php to populate the forms and i want the lunch mains, jacket potato and salad in separate lists, if they are all the same name they will all list under the same heading.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how radio-buttons are intended to work. Rather than give different names, give different `data-*` attributes. Common `name` attributes keep radio functionality, while the custom `data-*` attr will give you what you're looking for, without JS!

You can use custom `data` attributes like so:

```
<input type='radio' name='lunch' data-mealType='lunch' />
<input type='radio' name='lunch' data-mealWhatever='cool' />
```

Comment: Would you mind showing an example of a radio button with data-* attribute? Thanks

Comment: @Exoon -- Yup, added to answer!

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution for you proposed question:

```
$("input:radio").change(function(){
        var currentGroupName = $(this).prop("name");        
        $("input:radio").not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

I depend on excluding the clicked item, and select every radio button out there, excluding the current group name and remove the 'checked' attribute.
not the best code out there, but matching exactly your question.

I've made a live sample for you, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhHpy/

**Update:** here is a new fiddle to let the logic work only for your target groups, and escapes other groups (link drinks as in my example): http://jsfiddle.net/EhHpy/1/

Comment: That example is perfect! exactly what i need, Is there a way to define which radio groups it will work for as i only want it on the lunch_main, lunch_jacketpotato and lunch_salad, I want them to still select a drink and a dessert. thank you

Comment: instead of getting all radio buttons in the page by the following query `$("input:radio").not`, replace it by only selecting those who belong to your desired groups, and deselect them as before.
I'll try to update my sample to match this result.

Comment: Thank you, would be grateful if you could. Do i just put that bit of code between the head tags in a <script type="text/javascript"> tag?

Comment: I've update my solution for your request, check my updated answer above.

and please let me know if this has work for you :)

Comment: I added this between the <head> tags but it dosen't seem to do anything. Do i need to include anything else? http://pastebin.com/JT9Zt2QV

Comment: i got it working now, but it only one of the exclusions that i added worked, Do i need to do it a different way when excluding more than 1 group?

Comment: you can give a comma separated selectors to jQuery,each one will exclude one of your desired groups, this way you can have multiple groups to be excluded.

Comment: and by the way, the code needs to be placed inside a `<script>` tag, not inside the `<head>` tag.
a sample maybe like the following: 
`<script type="text/javascript>THE CODE SHOULD BE PLACED HERE</script>"`

Comment: if you have found that my answer has helped you, kindly consider marking it as answer, thanks.